# Is there an up-to-date user-made variation of the Lagarith Lossless Video Codec?

Tags: open-source, codec, video-codecs

For gameplay recording I use Dxtory and the [Lagarith Lossless Video Codec](http://lags.leetcode.net/codec.html) . However, the last update was December 2011. About 1 year ago.

Are there any users out there that actively continue to update, tweak and release their versions of Lagarith Lossless Video Codec ?

Just like the many version of Media Player Classic or the DOSBox Emulators, where user pick up the old version and continue to develop and release it.

Anything like that for Lagarith Lossless Video Codec out there? I REALLY like Lagarith because it's perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some search, and these are my results:

Lagarith is a fork of the [Huffyuv codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffyuv) offering better compression at the cost of sometimes reduced speed.

Support for the Lagarith codec is included in [libavcodec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec).
However, I don't believe that any independent development of the codec was done there.

Lagarith codec support was added in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) 2.0.0.
But curiously enough, in the [VLC Features Formats](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_Features_Formats) this format is listed as "Huffyuv / <strike>Lagarith</strike>", so certainly no development of the codec was done there.

So unfortunately I cannot find any trace of anyone else than Ben Greenwood that is
currently developing this codec.

<sub>Remark: I only posted this negative answer in order to share these results.</sub>